# How to get TimeZone.getDisplayName(locale) value to return non-English text?

Tags: java, internationalization

The code below outputs "Japan Standard Time".

`TimeZone tz = TimeZone.getTimeZone("Asia/Tokyo");

Locale locale = new Locale("ja_JP");

System.out.println(tz.getDisplayName(locale));`

I am expecting it to output something with Kanji along the lines of "日本標準時".  It does not seem to matter what timezone ID or locale I pass to getDisplayName()--the resulting text is always English.  How do I get the localized values?

I am using Sun Java SDK/JRE version 1.6.0_18.  I also tried running the tzupdater utility but got no change in results.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It works if you use the predefined `JAPAN` locale:

```
System.out.println(tz.getDisplayName(Locale.JAPAN));
```

At least, it print a bunch of questions marks on my console, rather than "Japan Standard Time", which has to be a good sign.

`Locale.JAPAN` is defined as `new Locale("ja_JP_", "ja", "JP")`, so there's clearly some subtlety here in the constructor arguments.

Comment: ISO language and country codes are not always consistent. While "JP" is the country code for Japan (country codes are usually written in upper case), the language code for Japanese is "ja" (language codes are usually written in lower case).

Comment: Isn't it high time to configure your IDE console to output UTF-8? ;)

Comment: Thank you, both.  Skaffman clued me into the problem being the locale.  If I create a new locale like `new Locale("ja", "JP");` it will also work.